# why does changing the css cursor property stop my ajax post from working?

Tags: jquery, css, post, mouse-cursor

I have an unusual issue that doesn't really make sense to me and was hoping someone might be able to give me a clue here as to what is happening.

I successfully created a page that sends user data contained in client side jquery via a jquery ajax post request

like this:

```
jQuery("#placelistitem1").click(function() {
     
     var inputVal = jQuery("#edit-location").val();
     //alert('hi');
          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "/createtrips/updateitin",
            type: 'POST',
            //data: {place1: inputVal, place2: 'London'},
            data: placesfortrip,
            dataType: 'json',
            });
     
     jQuery("#edit-submit").click();
     
});
```

I also want the div that I'm using as button ("#placelistitem1") to have a pointer/hand cursor when there's a mouseover. However, when I add that property i.e. cursor: pointer to the css of #placelistitem1 it no longer refreshes the page after the click..

Please note that #edit-submit above is a hidden submit button that triggers a submit handler. I've got a feeling it might be to do with that but I don't know why a styling CSS related property would influence event handlers or function calls (?)

Comment: Just a heads up: you have a trailing comma in the object you are passing to `jQuery.ajax`.

Comment: How are you applying the "cursor: pointer" property? Are you using jQuery to do it, or is it actually in a stylesheet?

Comment: Remove the comma following the `'json',` once it's removed your jQuery will *probably* work as expected...

Comment: Im using the cursor: pointer property in the stylsheet itself..

Comment: I removed the trailing comma and it still didnt work...but it still works without the cursor being set to pointer..odd

Comment: OK I think Ive got around it by applying the styling rule to a different element. It must be that if the element is used to trigger the ajax request theres a complication when that same element has a mouse cursor of pointer..I dont understand why that is but at least I can get around it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the following could be helpful, depending on what browser are being used:

> **Note on `pointer` and `hand`**
>
> In the past the `hand` value was Microsoft's way of saying `pointer`; and
>   IE 5.0 and 5.5 only support `hand`. Because it's the cursor value that's
>   used most often, most other browsers have also implemented `hand`.
>
> Since IE 6 and 7 support `pointer`, there's no more reason to use `hand`,
>   except when older IEs are part of your target audience. In that case,
>   the only cross-browser syntax is:
>
> ```
> element {
>   cursor: pointer;
>   cursor: hand;
> }
> ```
>
> Note that the two declarations **must be in this order**.

Source:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html

Answer (score 0):

In the end I got around this by making sure the element to which Im applying the style rule for the cursor is not the same element that Im using to trigger the post. Not sure why that should cause a conflict but it seems to work with this restriction